# How to straighten an arrow/connector

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

How do I straighten this arrow between two rectangles?  I've right-clicked and picked "Straigt Connector" but it refuses to change.

[image]

This just happens sometimes, and drives me crazy.  The distance between the rectangles doesn't seem to matter much.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-connector-lines-arrows-or-points-5669491f-9fce-4676-81f8-ef4553788416

1. select connector
2. right click
3. change routing style.

Comment: I stated in my question that I tried that, right clicked and picked "Straight Connector", and that it didn't work.